# Running newer version of R from terminal when older version is invoked by default

Tags: r, terminal

I'm trying to run R from iTerm on an OSX computer (OSX 10.11.6). When I enter `R`, it opens up an older version of R, from the path `/Users/***/miniconda2/bin/R`. I would like it to run, by default, an R version found at `/usr/local/bin/R`, without having to enter the full path every time. How would one go about changing the location of the default R?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to the `PATH` variable preferring `~/miniconda2/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`. I'm giving you a few options here to help understand why it is happening.

Let's assume your `PATH` looks like this:

`/Users/me/bin:/Users/me/miniconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

## Modify PATH

You could  modify `PATH` to move `/Users/me/miniconda2/bin` after `/usr/local/bin` or remove it from `PATH` completely. The downside is that if you rely on other binaries in `~/miniconda2/bin` they will no longer be found when executing them by name.

## Move R out of the way

Another option would be to move `~/miniconda/bin/R` out of the way, for example using

```
mv ~/miniconda/bin/R ~/miniconda/bin/R-miniconda
```

Afterwards R will be run from the next location in `$PATH`, but if you update miniconda2 it may return.

## Link to R further up in the PATH (easiest/best)

Finally, you could make sure that there is an R executable in something that is further up the `$PATH`. This is probably the easiest and most effective option.

First, make sure you have a `bin` folder in your home directory. If this is not the case, create it using `mkdir ~/bin` and then restart the terminal. The restart should cause the code in `~/.profile` to add that folder to your `$PATH`. You can verify by doing `echo $PATH`. If this is not the case, add the following line to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In the example at the top, the `PATH` already contains `/Users/me/bin` at the beginning of the line (highest priority).

Next, create a soft link to the R binary in the newly created folder:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/R ~/bin/R
```

You should now be able to execute R, which will prefer the softlink created, which will execute the one you like. If it does not work right away execute `hash -r` or restart the terminal.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks @PhillipKewisch, your last solution worked perfectly. Just a note for any other inexperienced people (like me) who are trying to do this: to make a `bin` folder in my home directory and have it recognized at the top of my `$PATH`, I used: `mkdir ~/bin`, `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`, and manually put the export line in my `~/.bash_profile`. There is probably a better way to do this, but this worked for me

Comment: Thanks, I've added your suggestions to the answer. It is actually not a bad way to do it, I have the same in my profile file.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you happen to be using RStudio Server (open source) or someone is looking for how to change the RStudio Server default version of R, here is what I found when trying to answer the same question:

Starting in RStudio Server 1.3 (the newest version is 1.4.1106, released February 22, 2021), a user’s preferred version of R can be specified in the `rstudio-prefs.json` file in the global-level `/etc/rstudio` folder or in the user-level `~/.config/rstudio` folder.

See https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/02/18/rstudio-1-3-preview-configuration/ and https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/session-user-settings.html for user setting options in newer versions of RStudio Server.

See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200716783-RStudio-Release-History for RStudio release history and https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/redhat-centos/ for Red Hat downloads of the newest version of RStudio Server.